# JavaScript alert message

Tags: javascript, alert

I'm not sure, Is it possible to show an alert message when someone tries to copy text from the web page using JavaScript? If it's possible then how can I do this?

Please suggest, if you have any idea.

Comment: It is not possible. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I've got a news website. Some People copy my reports. So I want to put a small alert message for them.

Comment: They can still copy anything though

Comment: Yes. That's I know but I need to give a message.

Comment: You probably don’t need to give a message and are probably going to annoy legitimate users of your website. (And again, it’s impossible to display a message for all types of copying.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```html
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" oncopy="myFunction()" value="Try to copy this text">

<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert('you tried to copy')
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. It's helpful.

Answer (score -4):

Bascically what  you can here is to detect the key press of ctrl+c and ctrl+v, and do alert when those key events are triggered

```
var code = (document.all) ? event.keyCode:e.which;
var ctrl = (document.all) ? event.ctrlKey:e.modifiers & Event.CONTROL_MASK;
var msg = "Sorry, this functionality is disabled.";
if (ctrl && code==86) //CTRL+V
{
alert(msg);
window.event.returnValue = false;
}
else if (ctrl && code==67) //CTRL+C (Copy)
{
alert(msg);
window.event.returnValue = false;
}
```

And make sure the context menu is also disabled by

```
onpaste="return false;" oncut="return false;" oncontextmenu="return false;" oncopy="return false;"
```

Comment: Disabling the context menu is a terrible idea.